# Prevent Apache Virtual Hosts to respond to all ports

Tags: apache, virtualhost, ports

I am on a bit of a struggle here because of something that should be really simple to do but i cant seem to figure it out...

I want to have two different virtual hosts defined, for two different ports. So foo.com:81, and bar:82 serve different contents.
The problem is that if i access foo:82 Apache serves me the contents of bar:82.
What configuration is needed to foo only listens from port 81 and bar only listens to port 82?

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test1.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:81
<VirtualHost *:81>
        ServerName test1
        ServerAlias test1

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html1
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/test2.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:82
<VirtualHost *:82>
        ServerName test2
        ServerAlias test2

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html2
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
Listen 82

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
        listen 444
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
        listen 444
</IfModule>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1  test1
127.0.0.1  test2
```

Thank you for you time...

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? If so, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as accepted and/or upvote it so I get credit and others who read this in the future see that it solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the VirtualHosts you currently have defined, list only the hostnames you want (i.e. foo or bar) for that VirtualHost using the ServerName and ServerAlias (if needed) directives.

Then duplicate each VirtualHost, and in the copy that you made that comes first in the file for each port, just put ServerName www.example.com and remove ServerAlias, and set the DocumentRoot for that VirtualHost to point to some folder which has an index.html file in it which says "We're sorry, but you accessed this site with an invalid URL."